# WSO2 API Manager - Swagger UI fails to load (API Console)

Tags: api, wso2, swagger, swagger-ui, wso2-api-manager

When creating an API , the definition fails to load in the API Store.

The swagger definition is created without any error in the API managers swagger editor(fig 2)  , and on the online editor(fig 3).

On the API Store , under API Console , it just says [image: API Store] :

```
fetching resource list: https://10.0.2.15:9443/store/api-docs/admin/Test/1.0.0
```

Full swagger.yaml :

```
swagger: "2.0"
paths:
  /lookup/node/insert:
    post:
      x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
      summary: Insert Node
      tags:
        - Node
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      description: "Insert a new `Node` record."
      parameters:
        - in: body
          description: Node object that needs to be inserted
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/NodeInput"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Node successfully inserted
        "400":
          description: The value for Node Code and Node Description must be unique
        "405":
          description: Invalid input
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
      operationId: insertNode
  /lookup/node/update:
    post:
      x-auth-type: "Application & Application User"
      summary: Update Node
      tags:
        - Node
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      description: "Update an existing `Node` record"
      parameters:
        - in: body
          description: Node object that needs to be updated
          name: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/NodeInput"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Node successfully updated
        "400":
          description: Specified Node does not exist
        "405":
          description: Invalid input
        default:
          description: Unexpected error
      operationId: updateNode
definitions:
  NodeInput:
    type: object
    properties:
      supplierName:
        description: The name of the supplier
        type: string
      logisticsServiceProvicerName:
        description: The name of the logistics service provider
        type: string
      nodeCloseDate:
        description: The date the node closed
        format: date
        type: string
      nodeName:
        description: The name of the node
        type: string
      nodeTypeIdNo:
        description: Unique identifier for the node type
        type: integer
      username:
        description: The user that last updated the record
        type: string
      nodeOpenDate:
        description: The date the node opened
        type: string
        format: date
      postalCode:
        description: The postal code of the node
        type: string
      nodeConceptDesc:
        description: The description of the node concept
        type: string
      nodeTypeDesc:
        description: The description of the node type
        type: string
      longitude:
        description: Longitude of where the node is located
        type: string
      nodeConceptIdNo:
        description: Unique identifier for the node concept
        type: integer
      nodeStatusIdNo:
        description: Unique identifier for the node status
        type: integer
      nodeCode:
        description: The code to identify the node
        type: string
      logisticsServiceProviderCode:
        description: The code to identify the logistics service provider
        type: string
      suburbName:
        description: The name of the suburb
        type: string
      nodeEmail:
        description: "The node's email address"
        type: string
      supplierCode:
        description: The code to identify the supplier
        type: string
      addressLine4:
        description: Address of the node
        type: string
      companyName:
        description: The name of the company
        type: string
      addressLine3:
        description: Address of the node
        type: string
      addressLine2:
        description: Address of the node
        type: string
      suburbIdNo:
        description: Unique identifier for the suburb
        type: integer
      addressLine1:
        description: Address of the node
        type: string
      companyCode:
        description: The code to identify the company
        type: string
      nodeTelephone:
        description: The telephone number of the node
        type: string
      latitude:
        description: Latitude of where the node is located
        type: string
      nodeStatusDesc:
        description: The description of the node status
        type: string
info:
  title: Test
  version: 1.0.0
```

[image: API Manager Swagg]

[image: Online editor]

Comment: The web console gives the error:  TypeError: Argument 1 of XMLSerializer.serializeToString does not implement interface Node.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I could not use the word

*nodeName*

as defined in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName .